# Jquery get/post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, date

How can i post date using jquery?I cam using jquery datetimepicker.i got the date from datetime picker.Now want to post it like

localhost/rnd/event.php?date=12-12-2012

in the same page i want to get the post/get value as

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    echo "got the posted date";
}
?>
```

Here is how i am getting my date from datetimepicker

```
$(function () {
    var pickedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {

            var day = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();
            var month = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth();
            var year = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
            var OutString = day + " - " + month + " - " + year;

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('event.php', { date: OutString }, function(result) {
    // do something with the PHP script's output
});
```

Comment: i want to run the same script after the get/post.And check if value is in get/post.what should i do in the section you said "do something in php"

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju, What do you mean by same script?

Comment: in the same page.i mean event.php.i have the datetime picker in the event.php.after selecting a date i want to post the date on url and check if posted or not

Comment: when i am in the page the url is : localhost/rnd/event.php  after selecting the date i want the url changed like : localhost/rnd/event.php?date=anydate ....and check in php if data is posted/or get

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use "get" to query data and use "post" to submit data.

just like Jon said:

```
$.get('event.php', { date: OutString }, function(result) {
    // do something with the PHP script's output
});
```

or

```
$.post('event.php', { date: OutString }, function(result) {
    // do something with the PHP script's output
});
```